# String comparision returning False even if they are the same in python , inside a html file in DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, equality

so there is this IF statement inside a html file , which is failing to return a TRUE when both the strings are the same , i dont know why , i copy pasted the same strings from database to another python compiler and it said TRUE but it is only failing here
I will add a sscreenshot of a reverse case where i will print it if they are not equal so you can see the string and confirm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqCG0.png)

this is the printed ones , i currently have 2 comments in my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mColD.png)

here it prints for both case ,hence shows how both strings are not same for both cases

im using django

one of the fields is  a CharField with max length of 500 and another
(post_id = models.CharField(max_length=500))

another is a uuid field
(id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4))

i tried is instead of == , still fails im expecting it to only return a TRUE if both strings are equal ( please ignore the != in screenshot as it is just to print out the strings)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

{% if post.id|stringformat:"s" ==  comments.post_id %}
this solved it , thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).